# Split array into chunks based on property being in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays

Have an array with objects.

It looks like this:

```
[{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:9},{id:10},{id:11}]
```

As a result I want this:

```
[{id:2,id:4},{id:9,id:11}]
```

Have no idea how to delete middle values (sine they are consecutive), and how to separate it into groups when we don't have `id`:5,6,7,8, meaning there is a gap in the sequence.

Comment: What is the logic behind the desired result ?

Comment: I write result that I want. delete middle values, and separate to 2 objects

Comment: this doesnt even make sense:
as a result you have two objects with two times the same key.

Comment: What if your input array has 7 elements, or 8, or 9, ... what is the general principle?

Comment: First split array in half, then take only first and last element from each?

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко if you only have 6 elements in a Array, and will be the same right order, why dont you just filter this array without Array[2] and Array[5]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Typical offtopic. No effort shown at all.

Comment: @trincot because it can be in random value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to split the input into parts where each part has objects of which the `id` values are consecutive, and then only include in each part the first and last object of that sequence.

That you can do as follows:

```js
var input = [{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:9},{id:10},{id:11},{id:15},{id:16},{id:17},];

var result = input.reduce ( (acc, obj, i) => {
    if (i && input[i-1].id === obj.id - 1) {
        acc.last[1] = obj;
    } else {
        acc.push(acc.last = [obj]);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: input can be this var input = [{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:9},{id:10},{id:11},{id:15},{id:16},{id:17},]; I want group it.

Comment: That is what this answer does. Did you test it? I just put that data in the snippet. Run it.

Comment: in  result must be id:2, id:4 - not include id:3

Comment: Sorry, I had to correct this: now the middle values are removed.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to happen when there is only a single value in a group. Like for `[{id:1}, {id:5}]`. Then what should be the output? Currently my answer will just produce: `[[{id:1}], [{id:5}]]`

Comment: [{id:1} ,{id:3.id:5}, {id:7}, {id:10,id:11}] for example

Comment: I suppose you want those elements in sub arrays, because what you just wrote is invalid.

Comment: OK, that is what my answer would produce. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the array and add object to new array if it match your condition.

```
var arrNew = [];
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var obj = arr[i];
    if(obj.id ==2 || obj.id==100){
        conitnue;
    }
    arrNew.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group it by the `id` and take different keys for left an right properties.

```js
var array = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 9 }, { id: 10 }, { id: 11 }],
    result = array
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            var last = r[r.length - 1];
            if (last && last.right + 1 === a.id) {
                last.right = a.id;
            } else {
                r.push({ left: a.id, right: a.id });
            }
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```